# How to get the request method type in `app.all()`?

Tags: node.js, express

With expressjs, `app.all()` handles all request, and now I want the request method type(`get` or `post`) in `app.all()`, but I don't know how to do this. I've been search in expressjs document, but didn't find anything valuable.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I've found it! [req.method](http://expressjs.com/tr/api.html#req.method) will do, so easy!

Comment: It's included in their example use of router but not in the api-docs under request. A bit weird.